# Trying to work on matrixes. my issue is i want the clean output to only have the number and 2 decimals after

Tags: matrix

Here is my code. the last part is the matrix that i need modified. I have it set up soo it outputs in a 5x5 just need help figuring out how to get it to only get the whole number and 2 decimals after.

```
import random 
row = 5
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(row):
        print(150 * random.random(), end=' ')
    print()
```

out put:

```
Clean Output
104.86809682138718 7.287319907187884 72.08751185471903 31.488701213829202 11.834191854073767 
71.3239776355152 138.36297456662746 37.108097158811475 76.53194065322288 99.30190230087226 
117.83335538511471 59.33203413507607 85.17705068201742 117.5328734531377 19.485982093453213 
43.98253383668171 3.106244396018154 123.59838274612335 83.83224026631217 1.348428243229599 
72.44033165452483 110.43794293932653 46.57612149896841 64.5849912656019 73.6110341987953
```

I tried to slice it usisng [2:] but that did not work. My issue may be how I have it formatted, any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

modified code:

```py
import random 
row = 5
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(row):
        random_value = 150 * random.random()
        print(f'{random_value:.02f}', end=' ')
    print()
```